# Google Spreadsheets append an array with timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this bit of code [here](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/03/google-sheets-move-a-row-of-data-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value/).

I modified it to better suit my needs. I'm using it as a dispatch log. In the deliveries tab, when I change the last column to say delivered it copies it to the delivered tab minus the the last column. And deletes the old row. It gets the job done, but I would like to edit it so that it adds a new column to the copied data with a datestamp included. That way when I view the delivered tab it will show me what date it was delivered.

I've tried and tried but my knowledge of JavaScript just isn't good enough. I've searched for a couple hours here and other sites for something that could get me going in the right direction to no avail.

```
    /**
 * Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 6 to sheet with same name as the value in column 4.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
  // see Sheet event objects docs
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  var r = e.range;

  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = s.getLastColumn();
  var nameCol = s.getLastColumn();

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

  // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
  if (colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);

      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      // ..but we can still delete the row after
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
      // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format

```
var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var timecell = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(), targetSheet.getLastColumn(), 1, 1);
timecell.setValue(timestamp);
```

Code should go after your copyTo(), and needs a header for the timestamp in order to work

Comment: using "GMT" is not a good idea as many countries use daylight savings and the result would be wrong 6 month a year... he best solution is to use the native spreadsheet method [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone())

Comment: @Sergeinsas cool didn't know about that, thanks. Updated with your suggestion